# Paragraph not aligning using <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my text in line, As shown below:

[image]

Investup and Real estate should be align, I need to move the Real estate paragraph with aligned to invest up paragraph.

Here is my code,

```
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center ">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <div class="service-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pie-chart fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>




                               <!-- <div class="larger"> &#9312;</div> -->

                                <h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">InvestUp</h3>
                                <p style="font-size: 16px;  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Investup is the tool for the investor to track the progress of the project in a timely fashion and recieve curated updates! </p>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <div class="service-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>



                                             <!--<div class="larger"> &#9313;</div> -->
                                <h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">CompareUp</h3>
                                <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Allows our investors to review the projects based on the most important factors, such as investment ammount, project timeline and location. </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center " data-wow-delay="0.6s">
                            <div class="service-item">
                                <div class="service-icon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-5x"><br></i>

                                </div>




                                <!--<div class="larger">  &#9314;</div> -->
                                <h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">NetworkUp</h3>
                                <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"> Allowing you to become the part of the Estateup global community and connect with them in order to spread the investment tips.  </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>



                    </div>













    <!--Innovate in real estate -->




</div> 
<hr style="color:#000000; width: 230px; display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;">


<!--Innovate in real estate-->

  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">

    <h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  text-align: justify; padding-left: 440px; letter-spacing: 0.3px; padding-bottom: 2px; ">Innovate in Real Estate</h3>
    <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; text-align: center; margin-right:20px;  "><br> Real Estates transactions have always had four parties involved. The buyer, the buyers broker, the seller and the sellers broker.</p>
```

My `padding-right` is somehow not working. Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: write and upload your code to fiddle, so that its easy to help

Comment: you dint give your invest up para code?

Comment: Edited @GaneshPutta

Comment: Do u want both paragraphs should be aligned to left or right or center?

Comment: @GaneshPutta i want the real estate paragraph to be aligned with the investup, if you look at the image real estate is on right side,i need to make it left so that it align with the investup text

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the complete code we could help you much better. If i understood you right this could be helpful anyways.

> i need to move the Real estate a bit left

To do so, you could either use `padding-left` or `margin-left` to manage the space to the left site of the element. Knowing the difference between padding and margin would be helpfull, you can read about this [here](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/).

I would recommend putting both elements in one `DIV` and assign margin to this one. This assigns the same margin to both elements.

**EDIT**

You added your code, so here my solution:

```
<div class="content">
<h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">InvestUp</h3>
<p style="font-size: 16px;  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Investup is the tool for the investor to track the progress of the project in a timely fashion and recieve curated updates!</p>

<p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"><br> Real Estates transactions have always had four parties involved.</p>
<div class="sec-title text-center" style="padding-bottom:3px; ">                        
    <div id="" class="btn-group btn-group-lg text-center" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" style="  width:300px;height:60px; font-weight:800; font-size:18px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
" style="">Enter Now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can assign margin to the "content" class using css:

```
.content{
  margin-left: 20px
}
```

Comment: now check the question,i have added the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

i have aligned both paragraph to left, if u want you can align it the center also, check below code

```html
<h3 style="font-size: 18px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">InvestUp</h3>
                            <p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; text-align: left; margin-right:20px; padding-right:20px;  ">Investup is the tool for the investor to track the progress of the project in a timely fashion and recieve curated updates! </p>

<p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; text-align: left; margin-right:20px; padding-right:20px;  "><br> Real Estates transactions have always had four parties involved.</p>
<div class="sec-title text-center" style="padding-bottom:3px; ">                        
    <div id="" class="btn-group btn-group-lg text-center" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-center" style="  width:300px;height:60px; font-weight:800; font-size:18px;font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
" style="">Enter Now</button>
    </div>
</div>
```